# Angular error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or

Tags: javascript, angular

There are many similar questions and answers about the error: *If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.* The solution is to define **name** attribute as described in the message. But this doesn't work for me. I have the next markup in my app.component.html:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" #form="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="input1" name="input1" [(ngModel)]="metaScript" />
    ...
```

And I still have the error in app.component.html line 3: *If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or...*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error happened because below in html markup one more line existed without the **name** attribute.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" #form="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="input1" name="input1" [(ngModel)]="metaScript" />
    ... 
    <input id="input2" [(ngModel)]="metaScriptMessage"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

But the browser still reports the first row has the error. And it's difficult to discover the source of mistake if you have other elements between these two.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First please inject FormsModule into your app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    .......
  ]
})
```

Now in your template app.component.html file

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" #form="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" [(ngModel)]="metaScript" />
    ...
```

Note: Request you to put type="text" in your input element like above